# Python-same code gives different output in IDLE and Komodo Edit

Tags: python-3.x

I have just begun learning to code in Python.

The following code gives one result in Python's IDLE and a different result in Komodo Edit.

```
a=1000                                        
b=1000            
print (a is b)
```

In IDLE the output is **False**
In Komodo Edit the output is **True**

Which is correct? Are they the same object or not.
I found the same thing with strings:

```
a='hello world'                                                           
b='hello world'                                                   
print(a is b)
```

In Komodo Edit the output is **true**
but in Python's IDLE it's **False.**

I need to know two things:
a) Are these objects same or not
b) whether I should quit Komodo Edit and learn coding
in IDLE only?

If possible is there any good article that lucidly
explains how Python manages the memory allocation?

Comment: you can use id() to see the memory

Comment: https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython#-strings-can-be-tricky-sometimes- talks about this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is false, because a and b aren't same objects.